# Join multiple strings from php & sql foreach loop and return as 1 string

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm trying to build a permission/action control system for my users.

There are 3 tables:

**appName_actions:**

[image]

**appName_roles:**

[image]

**appName_roles_members:**

[image]

There are 2 functions that will obtain the relevant data:

```
$memRoleIDs = AccessControl::get_memberRoleIDs($appName);
$memActionIDs = AccessControl::get_memberActionIDs($appName, $memRoleIDs);
```

get_memberRoleIDs works fine, it targets member 327 and returns the desired '2,4'

That is then passed to get_memberActionIDs as '2,4'

It's at this point I'm having trouble working out how to return **all** the actionIDs in one variable/string.

**get_memberActionIDs:**

```
public static function get_memberActionIDs($appName = NULL, $memRoleIDs = NULL)
{        
    if($appName !== NULL && $memRoleIDs !== NULL)
    {
        $tbl = 'app_'.$appName.'_roles';
        $memRoleID = explode(',',$memRoleIDs);

        foreach($memRoleID as $value)
        {
            $db = openDB();
            $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT actionIDs FROM $tbl WHERE roleID = '$value'");

            if(!$sql->execute())
            {
                logThis('ERROR_crit' , 'Database Query Failed !!!' , 1 , __FILE__ , __LINE__);
                die('<h2>There was a critical error and data has not been loaded correctly. Developers have been notified.</h2><h3>Please try reloading the page</h3>');
            }
            else
            {
                // sql executed ok - bind fetch results
                $sql->bind_result($actionID);
                $sql->fetch();
                print $actionID.'<br>';
            }
        }// return all the actionIDs as 1 variable here
    }

}// end func
```

Now with this, there is success up-to-a-point. It prints out the correct info:

```
1,2,3,4
5
```

And this is where I cannot go any further :(

I've looked into GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT in the SELECT statement and .= in the PHP loop, but I just cannot figure this out.

I'd like to return this as '1,2,3,4,5' all in 1 string.

If you could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful :)

Comment: What is the type of actionIDs? Is that a json?

Comment: 1) you should not store delimited data in a single field. Learn about normalisation. 2) you wrote you tried group_concat and concatenation in php, but you did not include any of your attempts. In its current format your question will not be that well received because of this omission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing out separate results, create a single string and print after the loop exits. You say you've tried this but you didn't include the relevant code to check if the implementation is correct. Is this what you did?

```
public static function get_memberActionIDs($appName = NULL, $memRoleIDs = NULL)
{        
if($appName !== NULL && $memRoleIDs !== NULL)
{
    $tbl = 'app_'.$appName.'_roles';
    $memRoleID = explode(',',$memRoleIDs);
    $result = "";

    foreach($memRoleID as $value)
    {
        $db = openDB();
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT actionIDs FROM $tbl WHERE roleID = '$value'");

        if(!$sql->execute())
        {
            logThis('ERROR_crit' , 'Database Query Failed !!!' , 1 , __FILE__ , __LINE__);
            die('<h2>There was a critical error and data has not been loaded correctly. Developers have been notified.</h2><h3>Please try reloading the page</h3>');
        }
        else
        {
            // sql executed ok - bind fetch results
            $sql->bind_result($actionID);
            $sql->fetch();
            $result .= $actionID;
        }
    }// return all the actionIDs as 1 variable here
    print $result.'<br>';
}

}// end func
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that but it didn't work. Obviously something was amiss when I did it, as after trying your syntax it worked perfectly! Many thanks. To the other guy who said I should look into normalisation, I will and thank you too.